# Can we increase answer acceptance rate?

Tags: discussion

While I think MageStackDay is a great idea, wouldn't it be nice to see a greater percentage of answers accepted which would I think have the knock on effect of encouraging people to answer more questions?

We don't obviously want answers just for the sake of it, content should remain good, but looking through the most recent 7 pages of questions (so 105 questions) 44 of the questions have answers, but only 11 have been accepted by the OP even though in many cases an answer is obviously correct and the OP has even confirmed this by adding a comment saying so, but still has not accepted.

This in turn means 61 questions don't even have answers.  This isn't great stats - rather sounds like a losing battle unless questions are realistically answerable and the incentive is there to post answers by knowing there is a good chance that one of the answers to the question is likely, rather than unlikely to be accepted.

Part of the problem may be that many questions are posted - and more increasingly it appears, that just can't easily be answered either because they are just aren't clear, are very store specific or just don't have enough information to allow them to be answered.

While a good majority of users attempt to post well thought out and complete answers, the same unfortunately doesn't often appear to be true for users posting questions which can be sloppy and lacking important information.

Don't ask me how to do it, but the solution appears to lie with those users who more ask than answer questions.  If we can somehow encourage these users to ask good quality, information rich questions and then accept answers as correct much more readily than they currently do, this would both increase the sites profile as a source for genuinely useful Magento information because of the high quality of the questions, but also provide an incentive for those questions to be answered because of the increased likely hood of an answer being accepted (not to mention more complete questions are answered more readily anyway with less need for clarification).  This is probably particularly the case with new users who are not an active part of the community often coming on just to ask their question with little other involvement afterwards.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5):

All of the topics in your question have been asked and discussed before:
 - [The quality of MageOverflow](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/q/317/146)
 - [Is it bad form to prompt people to mark answers as accepted? (During BETA)](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/q/106/146)
 - [Nagging for upvotes](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/q/225/146)
 - [How to manage new users?](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/q/192/146)
 - [Let's promote a Healthy(-ier) Beta](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/q/99/146)

There are also threads about this on the "Mother Ship" meta website:
 - [Force Accepted Answers on Questions by Inactive Users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8692/224252)
 - [Suggest Stack Overflow users with zero accept rates to accept some answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/90029/224252)
 - and others...

The conclusion seams to be that StackExchange sites are community driven websites.
You can nudge from time to time new users to accept answers that solved their problems, but until SE will have an auto-acceptance feature there is nothing much we can do.

If the user does not want/care to accept an answer there is nothing much we can do.

As for the unclear questions, flag / vote to close them.

The best thing I see so far is the *MageStackDay Initiative* that, based on the [stats](http://magestackday.com/#recap) from the first edition did a good job.
The stats are even better, because the MageStackDay Spirit lived on for a few more weeks after the main event. You can see [here](http://anna.vape.net/magestackday) that on 2014-12-09  we got to an answer rate of 73.52. Then the holidays came and everyone started drinking.
Let's get the as many people involved as possible for MageStackDay Reloaded maybe we can do an even better job this time.

Comment: Didn't realise it has been discussed before, I guess that confirms it as a real issue. I totally agree that attempting to force users into taking a particular action is not the solution and will reduce the attractiveness of the site, but I also think that an auto-accept feature would result in some very odd accepts. It would take a rather paradigm shift to change the way the site is used so fundamentally, but it seems a shame that the great, but labour intensive MageStackDay (which is essentially active users cleaning up after others), is considered the only solution. Must be a better way!

Comment: @philwinkle actually makes a good, rather obvious point in at the bottom [here](http://meta.magento.stackexchange.com/questions/99/lets-promote-a-healthy-ier-beta). Perhaps the answer is just active users more readily upvoting good answers. This will probably have the same effect of encouraging more answers while at the same time resolving the problem of inactive users asking questions and not accepting as the upvotes will clearly indicate that answer as being correct despite it not being accepted.

Comment: @JonathanHussey. I didn't say MageStackDay is the only option. I said is the the best thing I see so far. I think everyone is opened to suggestions.

Comment: I agree, We should vote everything that solves problems. More on this can be found [here](http://meta.magento.stackexchange.com/a/206/146) explained by Beofett

Comment: Beofett makes a good point - up/down voting is more important than I had considered. I'm really not good at this myself so I will certainly try and do it more.

Comment: @JonathanHussey...28 votes in 1 year and 9 months is not that bad...oh..yes it is :). But I trust you will fix it.

Comment: Already started  ;)